# Outlook for Mac 2016 - Keyboard shortcut for email autocomplete (Windows CTRL + K equivalent)

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2016

What is the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> equivalent for Outlook for Mac? Or what could be the possible workaround if the feature doesn't exist?

Comment: Agree with Lauren. You may check this link if you need an official reference: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-for-outlook-for-mac-07ae68c8-b7af-4010-b225-324c04ac7335?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Try ctrl + cmd + c

Answer (score 15):

Would   CONTROL + ⌘ + C work for you?

Comment: This should be marked as the answer!

Comment: At least as of today, this works as intended.

Comment: Doesn't work for Outlook for Microsoft 365 on a Mac. Bard and ChatGPT say "Cmd-K", but that doesn't work.